# Shadow effects on ImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, shadow

I am trying to provide a shadow effect to my Imageview just like in this image.

[image]

but the problem which I am facing it is that the shadow is actually visible from the bottom of the Imageview.

Here is the code which I have done to add the shadow. The color and all is still not matching with this one.

```
          CAGradientLayer *shadow = [CAGradientLayer layer];
          shadow.frame = CGRectMake(-100, 70, perspectiveView.frame.size.width, 
           perspectiveView.frame.size.height - 20);
          shadow.startPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
           shadow.endPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
           shadow.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 
           alpha:0.4f] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], nil];

          shadow.opacity = 1.0f;
          [perspectiveView.layer addSublayer:shadow];
```

Please provide inputs. Also if the approach is wrong, feel free to guide me to any other approach.
Thanks in advance.

Also can anyone suggest how to provide a 3D border just like in the image which provides a slight width to the image view?

Comment: If you could show us the screenshot of your image along with the shadow, it would be great.. Easy to understand..

Comment: I cannot post the images here as I don't have enough reputation points. So please help to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps, adding a shadow to the layer seems to work. You may want to try something like this:

```
//  perspectiveView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-50.0f);   
    perspectiveView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
    perspectiveView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    perspectiveView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6;

    perspectiveView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

You will need to playaround with these values to match your requirements. Hope this helps.

Here is my output:

[image]

Comment: How do I make it start on the left side and at the bottom of the imageView with desired x-y positions? This code seems to work actually so guide me to the further steps.

Comment: How can we Remove the whitish color surrounding the shadow?

Comment: There is no white around the shadow. It is just the opacity level that makes it so. You may need to increase the opacity to see if that looks good. Maybe, perspectiveView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;

Comment: Ok Genie I will try that out

Comment: Can you please tell me how to provide a 3D border just as in the image?

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
- (void)setShadow {
    [perspectiveView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(-5.0, 5.0)];
    [perspectiveView.layer setShadowRadius:5.0];
    [perspectiveView.layer setShadowOpacity:1.0];

}
```

Comment: This method is doing nothing. I don't know why but it is not getting the work done at all.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `CALayer` class , the layer can manage your visual aspects like  background color, border,  shadow and with it you can also manage the geometry of it content like size , transform etc .

visual effect(shadowing)

```
self.yourView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
self.yourView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
self.yourView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
```

and you also used it for like `self.yourView.layer.frame`(Geometry)

more info https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Below code work i have checked properly.

but **Shikhar varshney** can u check setShadow method call and perspectiveView is not nil.

```
- (void)setShadow {
    perspectiveView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 
       alpha:0.4f] CGColor;
    perspectiveView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    perspectiveView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    perspectiveView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0;
    perspectiveView.clipsToBounds = NO;
}
```