# How to give shadow like card in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to give shadow effect like card similar to the image in my iOS app

[image]

I need this on UITableViewCell the image will not work for me also the the gaps between cells with shadow effect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shadow effects on ImageView in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222595/shadow-effects-on-imageview-in-ios)

Comment: This is the holy grail in iOS apps :D

Comment: @Tarun - how did implement the "Card Style" table view Cells?

Comment: I have used UIView inside the UITableViewCell and placed my content over it, so you can adjust this container view as per your card design you can also use UIImageView behind your subviews

Comment: Check this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEuoaTF1bok

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a container view inside your table view cell and assign tag say 99.
Keep the cell height a bit larger then your card (container view).

and give shadow to your card view

```
UIView* shadowView = [cell viewWithTag:99];
shadowView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:228.0/255.0 green:228.0/255.0 blue:228.0/255.0 alpha:0.5];
[shadowView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[shadowView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[shadowView.layer setBorderWidth:0.2f];
[shadowView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:225.0/255.0 green:228.0/255.0 blue:228.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
[shadowView.layer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
[shadowView.layer setShadowRadius:5.0];
[shadowView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f)];
```

Comment: What if the view with tag 99 doesn't exist. please explain your answer

Comment: If you don't want to use tags you can create Custom cell and use properties or can use IBOutlets, probably you need to define custom UITableViewCell then

Answer (score 11):

**An improvised solution on swift 3.0:**

```
extension UIView {

    func setCardView(){
        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        layer.borderColor  =  UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 5.0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowColor =  UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:5, height: 5)
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

On cellForRowAt indexPath:

```
var cell = UITableViewCell()

cell.contentView.setCardView()
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass the view parameter? Can't it be referenced to self?

Comment: This can be used for any UIView. If its for self, we don't need to use extension. Just use the code as it is. or self.view.setCardView(view: self.view)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone needs Swift version

```
func setCardView(view : UIView){

        view.layer.masksToBounds = false
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 1; 
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give shadow effect by using this code...

```
UIView *viewTemp= (UIView *)view;
viewTemp.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
viewTemp.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
viewTemp.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
viewTemp.layer.shadowRadius = 3;
viewTemp.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    extension UIView {


          func addShadow(){
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
            self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 12.0
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7

         }  
}
```