# Custom Card View design in Table View Cell in XCode

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Is it possible to create interaction enabled sidebar solely in the utility area of the storyboard, or does it need any custom UI class?

[image]

Related question: [How to give shadow like card in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445177/how-to-give-shadow-like-card-in-ios)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

Create two UIView like this

[image]

```
 - Set corner radius to the backView
 - Set corner radius to the frontView, only for rightBottom and rightTop portions by using below method

extension UIView {

func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Refer my code
https://github.com/leninsmannath/CardViewSample.git

Comment: This is perfect! Could you please add a brief explanation of the codes? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for accept the answer. I mentioned the GitHub url of my code. You can refer the code for more. Thank you.