# how to create UIimageView with shadow and subview on it in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

How to create UIImageView with shadow effect and subviews (small image icon and label) on it using objective C. Image may looks as follows:

[image: White image with shadow and small image and label as subview on top of it]

```
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIImageView* image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profImg.jpeg"]];
 image.frame = CGRectMake(40, 200, 150, 100);
 image.layer.cornerRadius = 9; 
image.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

// make new layer to contain shadow and masked image
CALayer* containerLayer = [CALayer layer];
containerLayer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
containerLayer.shadowRadius = 9.f;
containerLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.f, 2.f);
containerLayer.shadowOpacity = .6f;

// add masked image layer into container layer so that it's shadowed
[containerLayer addSublayer:image.layer];

// add container including masked image and shadow into view
[self.view.layer addSublayer:containerLayer];
```

I am not able to add sub image and label over that image.

Comment: What did you tried about your tried code?

Comment: see this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445177/how-to-give-shadow-like-card-in-ios

Comment: I have added my code for shodow and image view. How should I add small image & label on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImageView` border :

```
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 5  
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor     // Set as per requirement
```

**Subview** :

There is actually no need to take label (Title) as a subview of imageView. Keep it at the same level as imageView.

```
let labelTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: imageView.frame.origin.x, y: (imageView.frame.origin.y + imageView.frame.size.height - 30), width: imageView.frame.size.width, height: 20))  
labelTitle.text = "Title"  
labelTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray      // Keep it same as imageView's border color  
self.view.addSubView(labelTitle)   // replace self.view by imageView's parent  
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: labelTitle)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func shadowEffectImageView() {

    imageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
    imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
    imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
    imageView.clipsToBounds = false
}
```

Comment: Please add context to your answer and explain how this answers the initial question