# How do I programmatically make a TableViewCell appear as a piece of paper or 'label' against a grey background?

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app (Swift 4, iOS 12) with a number of tableviews, each with multiple sections, and am inspired by apps that have built a very elegant table by making each cell appear as a piece of paper almost, like a sticker, on top of a grey background. The header of these cells can be expanded (which I know how to do) but I have no idea how to go about creating this layout

I have no idea how to approach this, have tried looking for tutorials or online guidance how to achieve this effect.

Any guidance or a pointer in the right direction to online materials/tutorial that covers this would be greatly appreciated!

[Image below is an example of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx1jo.jpg)

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow, please first provide your own code implementation to a problem and then you might expect some input and insights about how to fix your problems from others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a material design insipired layout, have a look at google material design, you will find several approaches to implement what you are asking. I did a very quick research and found this library https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material that implements the material layout, have a look at https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material#imagecard

You can also customize a UIView to behave like the card and add your elements on top of it, if you are in a rush go for the library.

Comment: Thanks a lot @caiomcg! Really appreciate it.
After more searching I also just found this other thread, for those interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445177/how-to-give-shadow-like-card-in-ios

Peter